# How to disable IPv6 dhcpstaticipcoexistence on Server 2019

Tags: networking, ipv6, windows-server-2019, netsh, dhcpv6

I have a Server 2019 host that has a static IPv6 address. It seems Microsoft [added a feature in Windows 10](https://trae.sk/view/34/) that is also present in 2019 where a host can have both a static IP address, as well as a DHCP address. This feature is enabled by default:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh interface ipv6 show interfaces 3

Interface Ethernet Parameters
----------------------------------------------
<snip>
DHCP/Static IP coexistence         : enabled
```

I don't appear to be able to disable it though; for testing I ran the command with the "enabled" option that works - but changing "enabled" to "disabled" gives me "Parameter is incorrect".

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh interface ipv6 set interface "3" dhcpstaticipcoexistence=enabled
Ok.

C:\Windows\system32>netsh interface ipv6 set interface "3" dhcpstaticipcoexistence=disabled
The parameter is incorrect.

C:\Windows\system32>netsh interface ipv6 set interface "3" dhcpstaticipcoexistence=no
The parameter is incorrect.

C:\Windows\system32>netsh interface ipv6 set interface "3" dhcpstaticipcoexistence=false
The parameter is incorrect.
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just broken? How do we get rid of this additional DHCPv6 address?

Note we have also disabled SLAAC etc as per: [Win2k8R2 Obtaining DHCPv6 address, but has static configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/370983/win2k8r2-obtaining-dhcpv6-address-but-has-static-configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try test command from PowerShell

Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 3 -addressFamily IPv6 -dhcp Disabled

Comment: OK, that appears to have gotten rid of the DHCP address, but "DHCP/Static IP coexistence" is still "enabled"... Hopefully the address will stay away though, thanks!